# Query Returned Incorrect Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query but getting wrong result. Let me share details with you. I have two tables. First is `tbl1`:

```
Id   |  NId  | value  |  VID
-----+-------+--------+-----
170  |  44   |   5    |   12
170  |  44   |   2    |   12
170  |  44   |   1    |   12
170  |  44   |   1    |   12
170  |  44   |   1    |   12
170  |  44   |   1    |   12
```

And the second table is `tbl2`

```
Id   |  NId  | value  |  VID
-----+-------+--------+-----
170  |  44   |   5    |   12
170  |  44   |   4    |   12
170  |  44   |   5    |   12
170  |  44   |   5    |   12
170  |  44   |   4    |   12
170  |  44   |   5    |   12
```

These are sample tables. What I want is to sum the column values from both tables and sum it and then minus it. Let me show you the query.

```
SELECT SUM(a.value) - SUM(b.value) AS res
FROM tbl1 AS  a
INNER JOIN tbl2 AS b ON a.VID = b.VID
WHERE a.VID = 12;
```

Sum of column value from tbl1 is 11 and from table 2 is 28. The result I want is -17 (sum the value from both tables and then minus them). But the answer I get is 23.

Comment: `database` tag is for questions about designing a database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to aggregate *before* joining, because there are duplicates in both tables:

```
SELECT (a.value - b.value) AS res
FROM (SELECT SUM(value) as value
      FROM tbl1
      WHERE a.VID = 12
     ) a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(value) as value
      FROM tbl1
      WHERE a.VID = 12
     ) b;
```

To see what is being aggregated by your query, run the query without the aggregation:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM tbl1 a INNER JOIN
     tbl2 b
     ON a.VID = b.VID
WHERE a.VID = 12;
```

This will help you understand what is happening in the `JOIN` -- and why your results are not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is by directly subtracting the sums:

```
select 
  (select sum(value) from tbl1 where VID = 12) - 
  (select sum(value) from tbl2 where VID = 12) AS res
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=135632f7a6f8d0e03eac9350618089fc).
Result:

```
> | res |
> | --: |
> | -17 |
```